# Algorithm for random answer/question order

Tags: algorithm

Imagine a quiz using a (random) list of questions. Every question has two properties:

- text
- answer

When a question is shown on the screen, three possible answers are displayed, A, B and C. One of these answers is the correct answers of the question, and the other two are answers from future questions. An example to clarify:

> Question 1: how much is 2+2? A: 3, B: 4, C: 5

After answering this question, answers B gets removed from the screen and a new question appears. Answer A and C of the first question remain on the screen, and a new answer B is added:

> Question 2: how much 6-3?  A: 3, **B: 6**, C: 5

Now answer A disappears, and a new question and answer appears in its place:

> Question 3: how much is 10/2? **A: 2**, B: 6, C: 5

This scheme continues for X questions. The easiest algorhitm to program would be to always replace the answer in question X with the new answer of question X+1. Of course this is pointless, because people taking the quiz would quickly discover the pattern that the newest added answer is always the correct one.

I can come up with a hardcoded order in which questions and answers appear on the screen, so that there is a good mix between A/B/C being the right answer, but I would to randomize this. I cannot find a (mathematical) algorithm that does this in a smart way. questions need to be random, but answers cannot. Sometimes the answer of question X should already have been added as option A B or C a few questions ago for it becomes relevant, but sometimes it is ok for the latest answer to be added to also be the correct answer for that question.

MY question: what techniques or algorithms can I use to solve this problem?

- input: list of {text,answer}
- output: list of
  {text,answerA,answerB,answerC}, where one of A/B/C must be the
  correct answer, and between two adjacent items in the list only one
  of A/B/C can be different.

Comment: What if the user chooses a wrong answer? Still the right answer disappears or the wrong answer disappears?

Comment: Nothing will happen if the wrong answer is selected. the UI/program only moves to a new state when a correct answer is chosen (apart from maybe a message appearing that the chosen answer was not correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my strategy. Assuming always the correct answer disappears.

1. Let's name the input question set as `Q`
2. Create an array(let's name it `A`) size of 3
3. Pick 3 questions randomly from `Q` and push them to `A` (Remove them from `Q`)
4. Pick a question randomly from `A`
5. Show the picked question's *text* and the choices are 3 *answer*s in `A`
6. User chooses one of them but we assume always correct answer disappears
7. Pick another question from `Q` and replace the current question in `A` (Remove it from `Q`)
8. Go to *4* and repeat until `Q` is empty

For the last two questions they would not have enough distractors, so you may generate random distractors or pick some of used ones.

% If `Q` is an array you can remove an element efficiently by swapping the randomly picked element and the last effective element. Then, you can do something like `rand() % NUM_REMAINING_QUESTIONS` repeatedly.

Comment: So the answers stay in their fixed place because an array is a sorted data structure and we replace questions at the same index in this array of 3, that's smart.